# Memory leak after calling Keras model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory-leaks

I wrote my custom Keras layer called `Material` and tried using it in my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

class Material(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=np.ones(shape=(6, 8, 8), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.k = tf.Variable(initial_value=8., trainable=True, dtype='float32')
    
    def call(self, inp):
        material_white = tf.reduce_sum(inp[..., 0] * self.table, axis=(-1, -2, -3))
        material_black = tf.reduce_sum(inp[..., 1] * self.table, axis=(-1, -2, -3))
        material_white = tf.maximum(material_white, .01)
        material_black = tf.maximum(material_black, .01)
        return tf.math.log(material_white / material_black) * self.k

def get_model() -> keras.Model:
    inp = keras.Input((6, 8, 8, 2),)
    material = Material()
    out = keras.activations.sigmoid(material(inp))
    return keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)

model = get_model()
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.01), loss='mean_squared_error')

board_tables = np.random.sample((100000, 6, 8, 8, 2),)
outcome = np.random.sample((100000,),)

while 1:
    model.fit(board_tables, outcome, batch_size=200, epochs=2)
```

For some reason it turns out to use more and more RAM after each `fit` iteration (I mean function call, not each epoch). At around 5 GB the memory usage growth slows down but still continues. And the problem is present both on CPU and GPU. Could anyone explain what is going on? Is there something wrong with my custom layer?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the same happen if you would just increase the number of `epochs`
> instead of putting your `model.fit` into a while loop? No?

Since you're training the model repeatedly in an infinite loop (`while 1`), the memory usage increases over time.

Try clearing your session after each `model.fit` iteration:

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Comment: This makes no sense, this is how all keras layers are implemented, the weight variables are only stored once (inside the class).

Comment: Have you tried? When I call the model.fit function multiple times (in a loop) I experience the drag, reported in the question, after a while. When I clear the session this issue is gone. It might not be the variables, I give you that (did edit my answer).

Comment: `keras.backend.clear_session()` does not change anything. If I just increase the number of epochs it does not happen. But I will need to call `model.fit` on different data, so I can't actually avoid using cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I used `tf.data.Dataset` created from custom generator to pass data into my model. For some reason the memory leak is gone now. But i still don't understand what's wrong with regular np arrays.

Comment: Same issue here. Can you provide your work around? I can confirm that the issue exists and clear_session() is not usefull at all.

Comment: @AlessioMora my code is so long and hard to read that I don't think it's feasible to post it here. Just write a generator that yields `(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are batches of inputs and desired outputs of your model. Then do `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(your_generator, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))` (with correct dtypes of course). Then do `model.fit(dataset, epochs=...)`. You can also provide `steps_per_epoch` argument to the `fit` method in order for it to stop after a specific number of batches rather than after your generator runs out.

Comment: And I don't create new datasets. I just made my dataset generator to yield whatever I want infinitely